# How to use AVAudioEngine to change EQ paramas when i use UIWebView playing a video?

Tags: video, uiwebview, avaudioengine

How to use AVAudioEngine to change EQ paramas when i use UIWebView playing a YouTube video? There is no video url,that's the problem.